# ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND ACPI ERROR: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS error while flashing UBUNTU 21.10

Tags: boot, acpi

I made a live USB to flash ubuntu 21.10 using the program RUFUS. It boots, shows me the desktop background but then crashes.

The message that appears when i try to boot ubuntu 21.10 from the live usb is the following:

```
[ 0.2551771 ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220) 

[ 0.2555611 ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [/_SB.PC10.GPP0.VGA], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326) 

[ 0.2555641 ACPI Error: AE ALREADY EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (202103 31/psob ject-220)

[ 0.255567] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [_SB.PCIO.G PPO.HDAU), AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326) 

[ 0.255569] ACPI Error : AE ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (202103 31/psob ject-220)´´´
```

Comment: Hello. When you downloaded and made the live media for the install. Did you verify the ISO before making the media?

Comment: How do I do this ?

Comment: Follow from this site. https://vitux.com/how-to-verify-download-in-ubuntu-with-sha256-hash-gpg-key/ or this official Ubuntu one. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview

Comment: Your hardware is too new for the software. Try a newer kernel that supports the hardware.

Comment: Do you have an AMD system? Take a look here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2462612. As you don't provide any information about your hardware it is kind of difficult to search for a solution for you. Edit this in your question.

Comment: did you fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED

I was able to boot ubuntu with safe graphics and load the Ubuntu's instalation tool. I installed 20.04 lts, as 21.10 had some hardware support problems, And it worked like a charm.

Thanks for the help guys, I will for sure come back to you.