# ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\ADGB], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kubuntu, 22.04, acpi

I'm trying to install Kubuntu LTS from a USB stick, but after choosing "Try & install" I'm getting the following error:

[image]

```
[0.219269] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\ADBG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20221020/dswload2-326)
[0.219280] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20221020/psobject-220)
```

In case it helps, when I'm starting my installed Linux Mint Cinnamon it seems to give a similar problem, but that only shows up for a few seconds, so I didn't worry and didn't manage to get a shot of the error.

If more information is needed, I'd be glad to provide it

Comment: These notices are not for us users but for bios manufacrurers and kenerl developers. See  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416198/ubuntu-22-04-acpi-bios-error-bug-could-not-resolve-symbol-errors-on-asus-x7  or https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot   or https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299214/acpi-bios-error-messages-when-booting-ubuntu-20-04  or https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411354/ubuntu-22-04-acpi-bios-error-bug

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND ACPI ERROR: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS error while flashing UBUNTU 21.10](https://askubuntu.com/q/1400763/) and [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/1190764/)